# Bug with single character tags in urls

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, filtering, search

**Works:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointers
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointers+c

**Fails:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c+pointers

It treats the last case as a single tag called `c+pointers` rather than two tags.

**Clarification:**

It generates the URL if you go to the page for c tagged questions(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), and then scroll down to the related tags sidebar and click on any other tag to form a tag1+tag2 filter.

Comment: This works!: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%20pointers

Comment: Enter the first URL, then scroll down to the related tags section, then click on the pointers tag.  That will generate the invalid URL shown here.

Comment: It's probably just the special case of c++ thats throwing it off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brad is right -- the decision to allow plus in tags causes us no end of grief, and results in a lot of contortions in the coede.

General rule:

- if any of the tags contain a plus, use space to delimit them.
- if none of the tags contain a plus, you can use plus or space to delimit them.