# Fix the single-letter tag "bug"

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, tags

As discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4384/bug-with-single-character-tags-in-urls), there is unexpected behaviour when a single-letter tag is the first one in a list of tags in the filter-by-tag url.  To get around this, one can use a space or %20 instead of + to separate the tags.  However, this workaround is currently only manually implemented.  If you hit the "c" tag, and then want to filter by one of the related tags like "c++", you have to either edit the url by hand and hit enter, or go to another page to clear the tags, hit the "c++" tag and then hit the "c" tag.

Neither of these options is nearly as convenient or obvious as just clicking on the "c++" tag.  It seems that it should be fairly easy to make the link delimiter used dependent on whether or not a currently selected tag contains "+", and I think it would improve usability.  So why hasn't it been done yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>It's because we hate our users. That's why.</s>

Well, users of "certain" languages.. anyway..

plus-delimiting is now detected this way:

1. must not contain a space
2. matches this expression

   ```
   [a-z0-9#\-\.]\+[a-z0-9#\-\.]
   ```

Comment: How can I argue with such conviction? :)