# Single character tag autocomplete for interesting tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-watching

The [single character URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4384/bug-with-single-character-tags-in-urls) problem seems fixed, but when trying to add a single character tag (I tried "r" and "c"), the autocomplete does not show it. As written by Eric, it doesn't stop me from adding the tag by simply pressing enter in the form.

Comment: It's working for me.

Comment: Agreed, no-repo here.

Answer (score 1):

When you type in that single word, the auto-complete does not suggest it. However, if you just type "C" and hit the Add button, you'll be interested in it.