# Bug: tag search including "C++" plus at least one other tag fails to parse correctly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search, tag-search

When searching for questions tagged C++, it works fine:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b

When searching via the search bar, typeing "C++ OR C#" yields the following URL, which is incorrect (matches "C# C++"):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/C%23%20C%2b%2b

When attempting to enter the search directly into the URL, the following shows up as "C blank OR C#":

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b+OR+C%23

But this one yields the correct search results:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23%20OR%20c%2b%2b

I believe (though I could be wrong) that the latter two should yield the same results, and so should entering the query via the search box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bug with single character tags in urls](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4384/bug-with-single-character-tags-in-urls/4424#4424)

General rule:

- if any of the tags contain a plus, use space to delimit them.
- if none of the tags contain a plus, you can use plus or space to delimit them.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/C%23%20C%2b%2b by searching `[C++] [c#]`